# Perl DBI / MySQL - can't for specific float values

Tags: mysql, perl, floating-point, dbi

I've got a problem with my perl and mysql code.

I have a database with a table "`STORAGEDATA`". In this table I have the column "`CLOSETIME`" with the datatype "`double`", which stores an `epoch timestamp` as a `float` value (the floating part represents milliseconds).

I now have the problem, that I can't find some of those values with a `SELECT-Statement`.

MySQL-Example:

```
SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = 1360021730.666;
-- This will find the data I am looking for

SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = '1360021730.666';
-- This works, too

SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = 1360209405.574;
-- This will find my data, too

SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = '1360209405.574';
-- But this does not find anything.
```

The searched values definitly exists in the table and are exactly saved as the values shown above (no trailing zeros or something).

Now I've got the problem that I don't know how to fetch the data using perl dbi.

Perl-Example:

```
my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = ?';
my @args = (1360209405.574);
# $dbh is a database-handler, providing the DBI-functionality
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
my @data;
if ($sth) {
    $sth->execute(@args);
    while ( my $dataset = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) { push @data, $dataset; }
}
```

This won't find anything, it seems like DBI inserts the arguments as strings. When I put my quittime directly into the code, it works:

```
my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = 1360209405.574';
my @args = ();
# $dbh is a database-handler, providing the DBI-functionality
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
my @data;
if ($sth) {
    $sth->execute(@args);
    while ( my $dataset = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) { push @data, $dataset; }
}
```

This will work, but that's not what I want to do. When I use DBIx, the problem is still the same. I could use "`LIKE`" instead of "`=`" to compare, but this would extremely slow down the query.

I tried to change the datatype for `CLOSETIME` to "`Decimal(13,3)`", but this didn't change anything.

I run MySQL in version 5.1.73.

Do you have any suggestions how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do withe Perl, it's am issue in old MySql version

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Either upgrade MySQL, or explicitly specify your predicate's type in the SQL itself:

```
SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = CAST(? AS DECIMAL(13,3))
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### Rationale

To my thinking, you show us the heart of the matter right away:

```
SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = 1360209405.574;
-- This will find my data, too
SELECT * FROM STORAGEDATA WHERE CLOSETIME = '1360209405.574';
-- But this does not find anything.
```

Huh?  That's not what I'd expect.  This appears to be a *bug* in MySQL 5.1, remedied in at least 5.5 (possibly earlier).  Smallest demonstration I could think of:

```
SELECT VERSION(), '1360209405.574' = 1360209405.574 AS "str-num comparison";
-- Under 5.5, TRUE:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e705e6/1 

SELECT VERSION(), '1360209405.574' = 1360209405.574 AS "str-num comparison";
-- Under 5.1, FALSE:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e705e/1
```

Under 5.1, explicitly CASTing to DECIMAL worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try turning on bind type guessing

```
 my $dbh= DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:test', 'username', 'pass',
  { mysql_bind_type_guessing => 1})

  - OR after handle creation

  $dbh->{mysql_bind_type_guessing} = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind_param`: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#bind_param

```
$sth->bind_param(1, $args[0], SQL_DOUBLE);
$sth->execute;
```